# PetaPoco to return self-referencing hierarchy

Tags: petapoco

How would one write a query/method to return a POCO that is from a self-referencing database as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942489/recursion-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you would map it a flat class. eg. `db.Fetch<CategoryDb>("select * from categories");`

```
public class CategoryDb {
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

From here I would then create a new Object that self referenced itself. (You could use the existing object with the ParentCategory having the [Result] attribute on it.)

```
public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

You could then take this and convert your flat list into a nested list.
I do have code somewhere that can do this, and for which it also provides searching methods etc, but its not on this computer. I will update tomorrow with a link to the code.

Comment: Done as you recommended and this what I have that seems to work. Will be interested tp see what you come up with:

var steps = stepRepo.GetAll().ToList();

            var parents = steps.Where(x => x.ParentID == 0).ToList();

            parents.ForEach(x => x.Children = steps.Where(y => y.ParentID == x.ID));