# created nested list in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create menu using `<ul> and <li>` tags. Im working in MVC3 + Razor. And I stored menu in database like this

MenuId     Name      ParentMenuId OrderBy

```
1      Item1         Null        1
2      Item2         Null        2 
3      Item2.1        2          1
4      Item2.1.1      3          1
5      Item2.1.2      3          2
```

The HTML output should be

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>`
 <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>`
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item2.1</a></li>
       <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Item2.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item2.1.2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Can anyone please help me how can I generated menu from this. I tried searching on internet, but not able to find something which I can use.

I see this article ([Recursion in an ASP.NET MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942489/recursion-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view/942616#942616)) where one reply is to create `HTMLHelperExtension`.

But not able to find out in my case how to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this :

```
@helper CreateCategory(int? nid)
{
        var childs = context.Categories.Where(c=>c.parentid == nid).OrderBy(C => C.order);        
        int childsCount = childs.Count(); 
        if (childsCount == 0)
              return;
        <ul>

             @foreach (Category child in childs)
             {      
                 <li>
                    <a href="@child.Url">@child.Title</a>          
                    CreateCategory(child.Id);  
                 </li>                                                                                                   
             }
         </ul> 
}
```

you most call this helper so :

```
CreateCategory(null);
```

hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DisplayTemplate
Here is an example:

```
<!-- Your view -->
@if (Model.Items != null)
{
    <ul>
        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
        }
    </ul>
}

<!-- Your DisplayTemplate control -->
<li>
    @Model.Name
</li>
@if (Model.Items != null) {
<ul>
    foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
    }
</ul>
}
```

So you will recurcively call DisplayTemplate from DisplayTemplate to render nested Items