# Most efficient way to store heirarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to store heirachical data in SQL Server and I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do so would be.

An example dataset would be:

```
Department Manager #1
  Product Manager #1
    Team Leader #1
      Team Member #1
      Team Member #2
      Team Member #3
    Team Leader #2
      Team Member #1
      Team Member #2
      Team Member #3

etc...
```

Comment: Efficient in what way?  Storage?  Reads?  Inserts?  Easy Joins?  Any solution is going to have tradeoffs.

Comment: What is the most accepted way of doing it? I would presume there must be a way that is a good balance between them.

Comment: Yes but there are limitations to any - if you use one table per level then adding a level is difficult.  If you use a self-referencing tale then querying is difficult.

Comment: CTE's (Common table expressions) and for XML path make the query easier anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
Person Table
- ID
- ParentID
```

Pros:

- You can support unlimited depth
- Easy to edit

Cons:

- Requires [heirarchical query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [recursive calls to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942489/recursion-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view)

You will also need to add a check to make sure that a person cannot be it's own parent (ID and parentID cannot be the same for a particular record) or you will have some serious problems querying the data.

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer is to store each object type in a diferent table, so based on your data, you need:
1 Table for Deparment managers
1 Table for Product managers
1 Table for Team Leader
1 Table for Team Members.

In Team Members table, yuo need one foreign key for each of the other tables.You could also save all the data on the same table, but you probably will have duplicated data.
Hope this help.

Comment: -1. Wrong universe and getting a HT talk in many projects, unless the tables are fundamentally different. JOB is not.