# How to pass a list of ViewModels to a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am quite new to C# and asp.net mvc and I have been trying to find an answer to my question here and in other foras but have not succeeded. However if this question has been asked and answered before then I apologize and could you please link to that post.

I am trying to create a treeview where I pass a list of ViewModels to my View.

I use code-first approach and have added a migration between my model and the database.

My problem is how to pass a list of objects of the ViewModel to the View? 
I can pass a list of objects of the model from the controller but how to pass a list of objects of the ViewModel? Is that possible?

Maybe there is a simple solution to this that I have not found yet and maybe I am doing this all wrong. Anyway I really need some help.

```
public class MyClass
  {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
  }


public class MyClassViewModel
  {
    public MyClass Parent { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> Children
    {
        get { return GetChildren(); }
    }
    public List<MyClass> GetChildren()
    {
        var listOfChildren = new List<MyClass>().Where(c => c.ParentId == 
        Parent.Id).ToList();

        return listOfChildren;
    }
  }


public ActionResult CreateTree()
    {
        var viewModel = new MyClassViewModel();
 //This only returns one instance of an object, how to return a list?
        return View("CreateTree", viewModel); 
    }
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to access the "viewModel. Children" which is List of MyClass

Comment: Check this out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-treeview-to-mvc-razor-view/

Comment: This as well, multiple examples for similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942489/recursion-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: @NirmalSubedi. I need to create a list of viewmodel objects and they each contain a MyClass object and it's children (which are MyClass objects).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have studied both these pages before, but will take another look, maybe there is something I have missed...

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you just pass the list of your view model to the view:

```
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult CreateTree()
{
    List<MyViewModel> viewModelList = MyViewModel.GetList();
    return View("CreateTree", viewModelList);
}
```

On the view, you set the expected type for the model via the @model directive.

```
@model List<MyViewModel>
@{
    //stuff
}
```

Now you can just iterate through your list of viewmodel.

```
@foreach (MyViewModel item in Model)
{
     //stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, however `GetList()` is not a recognized method..?

Comment: This is just an example of a method which returns a List<MyViewModel>.

Comment: Thanks, my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class, containing a list of your ViewModels

```
public class ModelWithListOfViewModels
{
    public List<ViewModel> ViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Add your ViewModels to the list in the controller

```
public ModelWithListOfViewModels model { get; set; }

[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult FillList()
{
    model = new ModelWithListOfViewModels();
    //Here you fill the list with the ViewModels you want to pass to the View
    model.ViewModels.Add(/** ViewModel here **/);
    return View("CreateTree", model);
}
```

Then simply loop over the list to get your model in the View

```
@model ModelWithListOfViewModels

@foreach (var vm in Model.ViewModels)
{
     //use vm to get access to a ViewModel added in the list
}
```